# UISearchBar color Messed up

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm beginning in iOS development and while trying to use UISearchBar the background color and forecolor combine in such a way that you can't read anything. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFEJO.png) is the image.

Forgot to mention that I'm using OSX Mavericks DP6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that control in the upper right is actually a UISearchBar

Comment: So you think that is messing up with the color?

Comment: What I was trying to explain was that there is no such thing as a UIScopeBar, what you are having problems with is the UISearchBar.

Comment: Thanks. Thought I saw something like it somewhere.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-production release issue that is very unlikely to happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that they fixed it on final release.
I guess that post wont serve as documentation at all.

Sorry.